# Python 3.7 - Passing a method that uses self

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, self

I'm trying to pass a method to class Fighter. The method requires me to pass the instance of a the fighter class where I would normally just be able to use self. Is there any way to use self in a function that I'm passing to a class.

The constructor looks like this `def melee_attack(fighter, target)` and I would rather it look like this `def melee_attack(self, target):` so that when I call it I can just call `fighter.attack(target)` instead of `fighter.attack(fighter, target)`

Comment: Yes?! What exactly is the problem with declaring the method like that? This needs more information.

Comment: I don't want to pass the entire fighter object into the method. It'd be easier to just pass the target if that's possible.

Comment: Still not clear enough to be answerable. If you declare `class Fighter: def melee_attack(self, target): ...`, it works exactly as you want it.

Comment: I'm not declaring melee_attack in fighter. I'm passing it in the constructor for Fighter, so that `self.attack=melee_attack`. I want to be able to use different attack type for different fighters.

Comment: OK, so probably https://stackoverflow.com/a/2982/476 then.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this.

Comment: Like this: https://repl.it/repls/HelpfulWobblyAudacity

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you.